# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:ldap-server'

Tags: spring-security, tomcat7, spring-ldap

I am trying to start application on Tomcat 7 which starts embedded ldap server.

That is my security-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="file:///${catalina.home}/webapps/test.properties"
                                  ignore-unresolvable="true" />

    <!--<security:ldap-server id="ldapBPS" url="${ldap.url}" manager-dn="${ldap.managerDN}" manager-password="${ldap.managerPass}"-->
    <!--root="${ldap.root}" />-->

    <security:ldap-server id="ldapLocal" ldif="classpath:test-ldap.ldif" root="test" />

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider
                user-search-filter="${ldap.conf.userSearchFilter}"
                user-search-base="${ldap.conf.confuserSearchBase}"
                group-search-filter="${ldap.conf.groupSearchFilter}"
                group-search-base="${ldap.conf.groupSearchBase}"
                group-role-attribute="${ldap.conf.groupRoleAttr}"
                role-prefix="${ldap.conf.rolePrefix}">
        </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Here are Maven dependencies, as far as Spring is concerned:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Using this configuration I get the following error during Tomcat startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 17 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/mifid/mifid-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:ldap-server'.
```

Any ideas where is the source of that error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am using Spring version 3.1.2

Comment: Adding the following dependency solved the problem:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Do not mix different versions of Spring Security. Just add these four spring-security-ldap, spring-security-core, spring-security-config, spring-security-web with version 3.1.2.RELEASE and that should be enough.